# running a script at linux startup

Tags: linux, shell, embedded, startup, embedded-linux

i want to automatically run a simple shell script at linux startup 

i'm working on **arm based board running a qtopia & linux 2.6.28** 

so,i put my script at /etc/int.d/scriptname and i make it executable using :

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/scriptname
```

and then i link it by :

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/scriptname /etc/rc.d/S10scriptname
```

the problem is that whenever i restart or switch the board off and then on again to test whether the script is running or not i find out that the script is removed ! 

i tried also to modify the rcS script that is located at /etc/int.d/ and add a few lines to test it but every modification i do is totally removed after i restart the board and i find only the original file. 

i'm still new to linux and i tried to search but i found nothing

thanx

Comment: What distribution do you use? On many distributions you have to put the symlink into /etc/rc2.d for example (or rc3.d depending on the target runlevel). If the file is removed that sounds like a security issue - does you distribution prohibit modifications to system-files?

Comment: i'm using qtopia with linux 2.6.28 for embedded systems not a desktop distribution , also i don't have /etc/rc2.d .. i only have /etc/rc.d and when i run "runlevel" on terminal i get unknown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some how I'm thinking you are running from a read only filesystem or initrd or initramfs. If that's the case you'll need to find out how to rebuild that filesystem.

How to do this varies by embedded system or distribution.

This might be a question for the electronics or embedded StackExchange.

Comment: oh , i'm using cramfs but i didn't know it's read only till now .. i'm still new to embedded linux and file systems .. ty very much :)

Comment: Yeah, cramfs is a read-only compressed filesystem that has to be built ahead of time. Embedded is a very different environment, all the other answers are correct in a sense but the assumptions were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your distro you have commands like 'service' or 'chkconfig' that helps you createing that links on the right levels.

Comment: well, i'm using linux 2.6.28 for embedded systems , i don't think it has a specific distribution name :S , or at least i can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/scriptname /etc/rc.d/S10scriptname
```

is wrong need to create a link file to

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/scriptname /etc/rc.d/rc *.d/S10scriptname
```

either use 3 or 5 
at the end of script please add
and add

```
rm -rf /etc/init.d/scriptname.
```

Comment: tried to format your code, could have got it wrong, though - please edit and improve :-)